# Cómo puedo verificar si existe un archivo con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Estoy intentando corroborar si existe un archivo en mi servidor usando Javascript, he podido conseguirlo usando el objeto XMLHttpRequest, sin embargo no es recomendable hacer uso de XMLHttpRequest pues es obsoleto y ya no se recomienda usarlo.

Alguien podria ayudarme a reemplazar dicho objeto por otro que sea igual de efectivo?

Aquí está mi código:

```
                let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open('HEAD','mi_carpeta/mi_foto.png',false);
                http.send();
                if (http.status === 200) {
                    output.innerHTML = "Foto existe";
                } else {
                    output.innerHTML = "Foto no existe";
                }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] Solo, para ser específicos en cuanto al lenguaje, que un servidor web responda a una petición de un recurso, no significa necesariamente que existe un archivo con dicho nombre en el servidor, pues el servidor web podría, por  poner algunos ejemplos, extraer el recurso de una base de datos, obtenerlo de otro servidor o generarlo _al vuelo_. Lo más que puedes hacer es comprobar como el servidor responde a la petición del recurso. Por otro lado, podría existir el archivo y de todas maneras obtener un error, por ejemplo acceso denegado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busqué información sobre [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) y no encontré que estuviera obsoleto. De todas maneras la función [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) sería su reemplazo natural

Para tu caso

```
fetch('mi_carpeta/mi_foto.png')
.then(response => {
  if(response.ok){
    output.innerHTML = "Foto existe";
  }
  else{
    output.innerHTML = "Foto no existe";
  }
});
```

Esto usa el method `GET`, par tu caso que quieres solo validar que el archivo existe, quizas sea mejor usar [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) lo que solo traerá la cabecera de la respuesta (no el archivo en si mismo)

```
fetch('mi_carpeta/mi_foto.png',{ method: 'HEAD'})
.then(response => {
  if(response.ok){
    output.innerHTML = "Foto existe";
  }
  else{
    output.innerHTML = "Foto no existe";
  }
});
```

Comment: En el Inspector de Elementos de Chrome me sale la advertencia que el objeto XMLHttpRequest está "depricated", recomendándome no usarlo :(

Comment: @Eduardo Yo uso Edge y no me aparece tal mensaje. Me parece que Chrome coloca un Link hacia una web que explica el tema, podrías pegarme dicho enlace??. Por último recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si es que ya ha ayudado. Saludos

Comment: Aquí te dejo el mensaje que me muestra Chrome cuando uso el objeto XMLHttpRequest:

Deprecated Feature Used
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: me recomiendas aún usarlo (XMLHttpRquest)? Porque estoy teniendo problemas con el uso de Promesas ya que no puedo utilizar el valor devuelto en mi código síncrono de Javascript  :(

Comment: @Eduardo vi tu otra pregunta, quizás la deberías haber enfocado más a tu caso particular para haber respondido como integrar el `fetch` a tu escenario...fue demasiado genérica la pregunta. Hasta donde yo se todas las funcionalidades marcadas como obsoletas siguen funcionando igual incluso las que llevan 20 años en ese estado. El ritmo de actualización de JS es desastrosamente lente (lo que para tu caso te beneficia) y las especificaciones no son obligatorias para los navegadores, y ningún navegador quiere dejar obsoleta las páginas antiguas

Comment: Entonces yo te recomiendo aprender a usar el `fetch` porque es mejor, pero si yo no tuviera alternativa y tengo que usar el XMLHttpRquest porque tengo que entregar la APP mañana, usaría XMLHttpRquest sin preocuparme, me jubilo antes que quede obsoleto. Asumiendo que existe el riesgo......muy bajo pero existe

Comment: muchas gracias por haberte tomado el tiempo en responder mis interrogantes, me da un gran alivio saber lo que me comentas. Igual creo que plantearé mejor mi pregunta más adelante pues como tú mismo señalas es mejor utilizar fetch y me gustaría implementarlo con ello o con async-await en todo caso :)